# django javascript no reload

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

how can i change url in django with javascript without refreshing

this is my code and it doesn't work

```
// script js
$(document).ready(function() {

    // initial   
     $("#contenu").load("{% url home %}");

    // au clic
    $('#lien li a').click(function() {
        var page = $(this).attr("href");
        $("#contenu").load("html/" + page + ".html");
        return false;
     });
});

// urls.py

urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('index', views.index, name='index'),
path('index/home',views.home name="home"),
path('contact',views.contact),
path('about',views.about),]
```

Comment: Do you mean changing the page address without going to that page?

Comment: in reality I want to change the content of the page without refreshing when I click on a link on my menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure you should just change `{% url home %}` to `/index/home`

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to Single Page Application? You can use Django to serve the API endpoints and use a different router for front end.

I chose React and react-router-dom in this case.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {
  Route,
  NavLink,
  HashRouter
} from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./Home";
import About from "./About";
import Contact from "./Contact";


class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <HashRouter>
                <div>
                    <h1>My App</h1>
                    <ul className="header">
                        <li><NavLink to="/home">Home</NavLink></li>
                        <li><NavLink to="/about">About</NavLink></li>
                        <li><NavLink to="/contact">Contact</NavLink></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div className="content">
                        <Route path="/home" component={Home}/>
                        <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
                        <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </HashRouter>
        )
    }
}
```

mysite/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('app1.urls')),
]
```

app1/urls.py -- Your frontend will use ajax or axios to call these endpoints to login or register a user, for example.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('login' views.login, name='home'),
    path('register', views.register),
]
```

I find [this tutorial](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/drf/) really helpful when setting up webpacker for React.